# Metadata Reject :The rating you’ve selected, 4+, is inconsistent with the content of your app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, metadata

My application is metadata was rejected due to below error.

"**The rating you’ve selected, 4+, is inconsistent with the content of your app. Since your application includes features involving Video submissions, it should be rated appropriately for this subject.**"

My application was not use any content which is show in Rating detail page. My app is upload capture video and youtube video url. so please suggest me what age rating is suitable for my app?

Comment: change into 12+ or 17+ -- if you are using 17+ you can't sale your app in some countries , in my choice change into 12

Comment: Use 17+ rating for adult content, your app uses the video content which might be adult video, that why your app is rejected. So use 17+ rating.

Comment: Since your app includes user generated content, you cannot commit to its rating being 4+, and the right thing to do would be to increase the minimum age rating appropriately.